# Azure EventHub - How to remove the event?

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-eventhub

Like allways, I would appreciate your help, as I am currently stuck!!!

We have a new project and we will be using the Azure EventHub. I have created  demo app, where we can add events to the Event Hub and also where we can consume them using IEventProcessor(Receiver project). The questions is that every time, I execute the receiver project, I see the same events. Shouldn't we expect that those events will be deleted-removed after we consume them?

Example in the Receiver project:

```
foreach (EventData eventData in messages)
{
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message received.  Partition: '{0}', Data: '{1}'",
                context.Lease.PartitionId, data));
}
```

Is there a way to delete/remove the event after the Console.WriteLine or will the message be retained for a day? With the Queues , you can signal the completion , but with the EventHub is don't see any command, I can use to delete/remove it.

Any reply would be greatly appreciated. We have been instructed to use EventHub but a-b reasons, its not a matter of choice.

Comment: How do you register your processor? Could add a bit more code? Are you using direct consumer or EventProcessorHost?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you call context.CheckpointAsync before exiting ProcessEventsAsync. That will store the client offset for the partition, and the next processor instance which gets assigned that partition will resume from the last stored offset.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn751578.aspx for documentation (not a lot of information, though).

Answer (score 1):

you should use the checkpoint and save the offset for the partition. AFAIK there is no way remove the events from the eventhub. It will be automatically erased from the eventhub after the events retention days. But I have also seen that we will get messages that have completed their retention days.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/93b1bf18-2229-4da8-994f-ddc7c675f62f/message-retention-day-not-working?forum=servbus

So I believe they will get removed automatically when you hit the space quota, or it will be like a scheduled task, not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

The events in Azure Event Hub will be removed after they are buffered for the defined retention period.  You can set the retention days from 1-7 days.  There is no need for removing them manually.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question at all. While it's true the events will disappear, the more important matter is *how to prevent them from being processed multiple times in successive executions of the demo app*.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all other answers, there's one more confusing point: EventHub may not delete messages older than retention period up to 30 days. It depends on load put over the hub.

E.g. retention period is 1 day, but if there're few messages they can be kept for a longer period.

Luckily they are not billed.

Answer (score -1):

The best option to consume an event hub is the **EventProcessorHost** framework.
It gives you the possibility to checkpoint any message you had already read. To do that it stores (in a blob storage) the index of the last checkpointed message in order to resume the processing in case of a shutdown.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2015/01/16/event-processor-host-best-practices-part-1/

Probably you will also need a storage emulator for development purposes, but if you have an Azure account you could use a remote blob storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator